# Retrieve current focused/mouse-overed hyperlink URL

Tags: javascript, firefox, url, hyperlink, focus

I'm working on an extension that I need to find a way to catch the current focused link.

When we hit TAB Key, or mouse over a hyperlink, we can see in the status bar (right side of the address bar for firefox 4+) the URL of that link has been shown.

How do you capture this URL with Javascript in Add-on online builder? how do I store it into a variable and whenever the focused link is changed, the variable value will be updated accordingly? I searched internet for hours and so far found this function called Document.activeElement.href ?? But I'm not sure that's what I need and if it is, how do I use it?

Please help!

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DmX5j/6/

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
   linkDisplay = document.getElementById('currentLink'),
   currentLink;

for(var i =0; i < links.length; i++){
    links[i].onfocus = function(){updateLink(this.href)};
    links[i].onmouseover = function(){updateLink(this.href)};
}

function updateLink(link){
    currentLink = link; 
    linkDisplay.innerHTML = currentLink;
}
```

pure JS way. Not sure if this is what you are looking for or not, basically on focus or mouseover the current link is updated.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
<html><body>
    <a href="#link1">link 1</a>
    <a href="#link2">link 2</a>

    <div id="output"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var handler = function() {
            jQuery('#output').text( jQuery(this).attr('href') );
        };
        jQuery('a').focus(handler).mouseover(handler);
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Let me know if you don't want to use jQuery, and I'll re-write my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `window.XULBrowserWindow.overLink` happens to contain the current hovered URL as shown in the status bar but it doesn't save the actual element being hovered.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to put event handlers on all links of the interest, this is quite easy using ***jQuery***, when the event trigger you can capture the **href** attribute and process accordingly

Comment: Thanks Everyone for the input, I ended up using document.activeElement.href and it works pretty nice. Appreciate the help and i will try out them too when i get a chance~ =)

Comment: Yep it worked nice, I ended up using some other way although. Thank you and thanks everyone.